# What is this isometric diagram that suddenly appeared in my AI drawing?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Adobe Illustrator 2020 on Windows. Shortly after discovering the Actions window and creating/using some new actions, I saw that a mysterious isometric grid graphic has appeared on my drawing. (Perhaps it had something to do with the instructional videos I was watching about Actions, that used isometric actions as examples.) I don't know how to get rid of it! Knowing how it happened in the first place may be helpful as well. [image]

Comment: It's the dreaded [Perspective Grid](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/perspective-drawing.html)!

Comment: Ah. I see. View > Perspective Grid > Hide Grid. :)

Comment: "dreaded" is being kind `:)`

Comment: @Scott i wonder if one could delet ethe feature

Comment: @joojaa, if so why stop there? 

Comment: This is the very least annoyance I've found so far on AI. The real problems are in the basics. That's why I was building actions.....creating FreeHand-like one-stroke replacements for some of the clunkety-clunk commands AI has. (Deselecting, cloning, etc.)

Comment: I've always wondered if anyone actually USES that thing, or if it's just there to annoy us.

Comment: @Alith7 the illustrator temleads dont seem to do very good job of refining requirements. The tool stinks of implementing a requirement with face value. The tool is useless. The problem is that they keep taking features out of  software like powerpoint. So the last time they did a good job was when they released shape builder. Which was the second iteration of live paint bucket. Its clear that they would like to make illustrator a indirect modeler but dont know how to do it. Last time they were succesfull was then they did the appearance panel but they dont seem to be interested in improving it

Comment: @joojaa agreed on all points.  Shape builder is an amazing tool that they don't feature well enough.

Comment: The Perspective Grid was Adobe's answer to users asking for more 3D capabilities in Illustrator. Please don't blame devs... they seem to have *very* little control over feature sets or alterations in Illustrator. I think they may, at times, feel just as defeated and frustrated as users.

Comment: @Scott im not really complaining of the purpose of the tool but its overall design. I mean simple things like no slanted horizon, modal nature and not being able to efficiently turn the grid are all symptoms of not understanding things well enough. I mean i can do 90% of the work wothout the tool. But yes its not really a devs problem its clearly a team leader problem since the gpu team works quite well

Answer (score 1):

It's the **Perspective Grid**.

To turn it off choose  `View > Perspective Grid > Hide Grid`

To learn more about the Perspective grid feature, [see here](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/perspective-drawing.html).